# change input submit value after onclick

Tags: onclick

i want to change input submit value after onclick but its not working and my code is as follows:

```
 window.callme = (function() {
        var update = true;
        return function(me) {
            if(update) {
                me.value = "Edit";
            } else {
                me.value = "update";
            }
            update = !update;
        };
    }());
<input type=submit name=update id=update class='wrap_2' value='update' onclick='callme(this);'/>"`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 2):

A function declaration creates a variable pointing to the function in the current scope.

In JavaScript, each function creates a new scope.

You are creating function inside the scope of the anonymous function you assign to callme. It is not a global.

The onclick event handler is not in the scope of the aforementioned anonymous function, so the variable is not accessible.

Please try something like this example...

```
   function callMe(){
         alert("Inside the function");
         this.value = "New Value";                   
    }


    window.onload = function(){
          callMe();  
          document.getElementById("thisCall").onclick = callMe;
    }
```

**EDIT:**

And this code :

```
document.getElementById("thisCall").onclick = callMe;
```

Is working because it's written inside the onload function scope, where the function callMe is defined.

And it will not work if you use it with the `onclick` attribute, because like said `callMe()`isn't recognized in the global scope and that's the reason why you got `callMe is not defined` there.

Hope this helps.. Let me know :)

Comment: Thanks its working but it doesn't display the second value, what it does when you click on the submit button it appear and get back to previous value again